# Shell script wrapper to prevent running command with no arguments?

Tags: bash, shell-script

There is program I use, say `xyz`, that has undesirable effects if I run the command bare with no arguments.  So I'd like to prevent myself from accidentally running the `xyz` command with no arguments but allow it to run with arguments.

How can I write a shell script so that when calling `xyz` with no arguments it will print an error message and otherwise pass any and all arguments to the `xyz` program?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check special variable [$#](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_05_02):

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "No arguments provided!"
  exit 1
fi
/usr/bin/xyz "$@"
```

Then, add an alias to your `~/.bashrc`;

```
alias xyz="/path/to/script.sh"
```

Now, each time you run `xyz`, the alias will be launched instead. This will call the script which checks whether you have any arguments and only launches the real `xyz` command if you do. Obviously, change `/usr/bin/xyz` to whatever the full path of the command is.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases the frame can be

```bsh
if [ "$1" ]
then
  /usr/bin/xyz "$@"
else
  echo "Errormessage"
fi
```

Comment: This will fail if `$1` is empty. See my comment in @chaos's answer.

Comment: @cuonglm In my bash version it is not. Checked `set -- ; [ "$1" ] ; echo $?` produce `1` without any error.

Comment: In order for this to be useful, the script must be named `xyz` so this will cause an endless loop since you're not using the full path to `xyz`.

Comment: @terdon Or even to be a such bash function `xyz() {...}`

Comment: Well, in a function, the `exit` causes the terminal to exit but you can just remove it, it's not really needed. The main issue is that unless you use the full path, the function/script/whatever will keep calling itself and enter an infinite loop.

Comment: @Costas: It's an error, status other but 0 indicate an error. Try `set --; [ "$1" ] && echo OK`.

Comment: @cuonglm if `$1` is null what kind of status your expect? From `man test`: `[ STRING ]` **True** if string is **not** empty, synonim of `[ -n STRING ]`. So try instead `set --; [ "$1" ] || echo EMPTY`